# find unique elements amongst the values of a map in scala

Tags: scala

I have Map[String,Seq[String]].

I want to find the unique elements among all the values in the map. I want to do this in Scala.

Say, I have

```
Map['a' -> Seq(1,2,3),
'b' -> Seq(2,3),
'c' -> Seq(4)
]
```

I want the desired result to be

```
Map['a' -> Seq(3), 'c' -> Seq(4)]
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: why does `a` not have List(1)? instead of List(3). `3` is common in `b`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for unique element in each list, then you can use `currentList.diff(rest_of_the_list)`

**Given**

```
scala> val input = Map('a' -> Seq(1,2,3), 'b' -> Seq(2,3), 'c' -> Seq(4))
input: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Seq[Int]] = Map(a -> List(1, 2, 3), b -> List(2, 3), c -> List(4))
```

**Find the rest of the elements for each key,**

```
scala> val unions = input.map(elem => elem._1 -> input.filter(!_._1.equals(elem._1)).flatMap(_._2).toSet)
unions: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Map(a -> Set(2, 3, 4), b -> Set(1, 2, 3, 4), c -> Set(1, 2, 3))
```

**Then, iterate over input map and find the unique element in each each list**

```
scala> input.map(x => x._1 -> x._2.diff(unions(x._1).toList))
res18: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Seq[Int]] = Map(a -> List(1), b -> List(), c -> List(4))
```

If you don't want empty keys (`b` in above example)

```
scala> input.map(x => x._1 -> x._2.diff(unions(x._1).toList)).filter(_._2.nonEmpty)
res21: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Seq[Int]] = Map(a -> List(1), c -> List(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the elements that non-unique by flattening all values and filter elements that size more than 1. Then, remove all non-unique element in every key.

```
val input = Map('a' -> Seq(1,2,3),
    'b' -> Seq(2,3),
    'c' -> Seq(4))
val nonUnique = input.values.flatten
  .groupBy(identity)
  .filter(_._2.size > 1)
  .keys.toSeq
input.mapValues(x => x.diff(nonUnique)).filter(_._2.size == 1)
```